# Does an operation have to be completely defined and closed on a set for it to be an algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

If we have an arbitrary operation $+$, and for example a set $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$, is that set still an algebraic structure if $+$ is only defined on $a+b=e$, and $a+c=5$? (where $5$ is not in the set). that means e.g. that $b+d$ is undefined.

Comment: What do you mean by "an algebraic structure"?  That term doesn't have a precise meaning in most contexts...

Comment: (a) When you say that an operation is defined only for some elements of a set you call it partial (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_algebra). (b) When you write $a+c+5$ it usually means either $(a+c)+5$ or $a+(c+5)$ and if your operation is not associative you should say which. Note that in the first case then $a+c$ must be defined. Perhaps you meant $a+c=5$? (c) if you are looking at the set $\{a,b,c,d,e\}$ a (binary partial) operation by definition should take pairs from your set to elements in your set (otherwise  why not consider a bigger set so that your operation ends up in it).

Comment: sorry it should be a+c=5 not a+c+5. In any case, so it is universally accepted that a binary operator is not allowed to point to elements in another set than the set on which that operator is defined?

Comment: @Programmer2134 At least the one I've seen, a binary operation on a set $X$ is $\textit{defined}$ to be a function $X \times X \to X$. So by definition it's defined on all pairs of elements of $X$ and the image of those pairs always lands in $X$

Comment: There is the notion of $2$-algebra: a $2$-algebra is an object $(A,B,f_1,\dots,f_k)$ with $f_i\colon A^{r_i}\to B$ for each $i$. So it is possible to consider functions whose range is different than the domain. The concept of *partial algebra* also exists, where the $f_i$ are only required to be partial functions. I don't have references to give you at the moment.